# mv: target 'XXX' is not a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

I am trying to write a bash script that will go through a directory
and rename the files (the file name is really crazy and is not recognizable to any human as what they are) to "Chapter1.mp3", "Chapter2.mp3", etc,
but when I do this, I get the following error:

```
mv: target 'Chapter##.mp3' is not a directory
```

As I recall, the `mv` command allows you to specify a filename as well as a directory... why am I getting this error? The following is my code:

```bsh
cptr=0;

for i in ./myFolder/*; do
    cptr=$(($cptr+1)); # I can't remember, can I use cptr++?
    mv -v $i "Chapter$cptr.mp3";
done;
```

I've tried removing the file extension, removing the quotes, even using the `cp` command instead, but nothing I have tried has worked. 
Why is it requiring the target to only be a directory and not a filename?

I am using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS terminal with Linux Subsystem for Linux;
does this make any difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have any filenames with spaces (or tabs or newlines) in them,
then you *need* to put `$i` in quotes. 
If, for example, your 42nd file is named `foo bar`, then

```
mv -v $i "Chapter$cptr.mp3"
```

will be expanded as

```
mv -v ./myFolder/foo bar "Chapter42.mp3"
```

which looks like you’re running `mv` with three name arguments. 
Running `mv` with three or more name arguments is valid
only if the last name is a directory (e.g., `mv *.mp3 my_music`). 
Since you do not have directories named `ChapterNN.mp3`,
you get the error you reported.

So do

```
mv -v "$i" "Chapter$cptr.mp3"
```

I said “If you have any filenames with spaces … in them,
then you need to put `$i` in quotes.” 
Of course I meant “You ***should*** put `$i` in quotes,
so your script will work
if you *ever* have any filenames with spaces … in them.”

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *This answer can work, but it is not a good solution. Please see the comments below and the answer that I have selected as the solution, it is a much better solution than mine.*

---

I was doing

```bsh
for i in ./my\ folder/*; do
    ...
done;
```

instead of

```bsh
for i in ./my_folder/*; do
    ...
done;
```

For some reason it wasn't liking the spaces even though I had the backslash, to escape the space, and so it was messing things up. I just renamed the folders with no spaces, and then it worked fine.

Comment: -1. Adjusting input data to flawed script is wrong. Fixing the script so it can handle any data is right.

Comment: Scott has the right answer. Variable references should almost always be in double-quotes, to avoid problems like this. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot this and many other common scripting mistakes; I recommend running all your scripts through it and fixing what it points out.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It's been a while since I took a class on bash scripting. Now that you pointed out putting double quotes around variables, I remember my teacher saying it was best practice, and that (like you said) it would solve these kinds of problems before they even happen.

Comment: @gordon thank you for that tool! I will definitely bookmark it for future use.

Comment: I edited my answer telling people to look at your comments and the other answer, because mine is not a good solution. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I removed my downvote as I don't want to punish you for sharing a solution, even if it's flawed. Adding the note was a good move.